# Segmentation Fault 11 - Finding Words in File in C

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I have a .txt file that is open and read with the findMatches function. The file have the following structure:

```
Auckland link42 link24 link23 link5
Wellington link3 link21
Queenstown link1 link9 link15
```

The request array contain keywords that were input by the user. I was trying to print only tokens that correspond to words in request.

For example:

```
>>> Auckland Wellington

Auckland
link42
link24
link23
link5

Queenstown
link1
link9
link15
```

However, I get Segmentation Fault 11. The error is not present if 1 keyword is searched, but only if 3 or more, and it displays only maximum two keywords with corresponding links (as above).

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

```
#define MAXSTR 1000

int findMatches (const char *filename, char *request[], int size) {

    char lines[MAXSTR];
    char delim[2] = " ";
    char *token;

    FILE *file; 

    if ((file = fopen(filename, "r")) == NULL) {
        printf("Error.\n");
    }

    while(fgets(lines, MAXSTR, file) != NULL) {
        token = strtok(lines, delim);
    
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            if (!strcmp(request[i], token)) {
                
                    while (token != NULL) {
                        printf("%s\n", token);
                        token = strtok(NULL, delim); 
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}


int main (int agrc, char *argv[]) {

    char *request[MAXSTR];
    int size = agrc - 1;
    int index = 0;

    for (int i = 1; i < agrc; i++) {
        request[index] = argv[i];
        index++;
    }

    findMatches("index.txt", request, size);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Difference in name is not a problem, but `argc` is commonly used instead of `agrc`.

Comment: Well done on improving your code from [yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65639291/passing-an-array-as-argument-to-function-in-c)!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this loop

```
        token = strtok(lines, delim);
    
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            if (!strcmp(request[i], token)) {
                
                    while (token != NULL) {
                        printf("%s\n", token);
                        token = strtok(NULL, delim); 
                }
            }
        }
```

When firstly the request is matched to the token, the `while` loop is executed and `token` becomes `NULL` after that. Then, the next iteration of `for` loop, `strcmp(request[i], NULL)` is executed and this leads to Segmentation Fault.

You should add `break;` after the `while` loop to avoid this.

```
        token = strtok(lines, delim);
    
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            if (!strcmp(request[i], token)) {
                
                    while (token != NULL) {
                        printf("%s\n", token);
                        token = strtok(NULL, delim); 
                }
                break; /* you should add this */
            }
        }
```

Also you shoudn't do `fgets(lines, MAXSTR, file)` when `file` is `NULL`.

```
    if ((file = fopen(filename, "r")) == NULL) {
        printf("Error.\n");
        return -1; /* you should add this */
    }
```

And you forgot to close the opened file.

```
    }
    fclose(file); /* you should add this */
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: One other nitpick, `token = strtok(lines, delim);` should be checked for `NULL` before entering the inner loop.